# How to check if the data is present for one column when date count present for the combination column is greater that 2

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table A:

I want to check if Name , class,roll,subjects are same then if the number of date present for this 4 combination is greater than 2  then check value of marks must be greater than 0.

```
Name    Class   Roll    Subject Marks   Date
a       1       1       abc     10      01.01.2001
a       1       1       abc             02.01.2001
a       1       1       abc     30      03.01.2001
b       2       2       xyz     10      01.01.2001
b       2       2       xyz             02.01.2001
b       2       2       xyz     20      03.01.2001
```

From above table,

Since a,1,1,abc is same , I want to check if marks has any value or not for date > datecount(2).
Which in this case is 03.01.2001
and also for b,2,2,xyz it is 03.01.2001

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by "date count is greater than 2"?  Provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Is that sample table data or the expected result? We need both.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the same using ROW_NUMBER()

```
WITH subset1
 AS (SELECT dd.*,
            Row_number()
              over(
                PARTITION BY name, class, roll, subject
                ORDER BY date1) rw
     FROM   data dd)
  SELECT marks,
   ss.*
  FROM   subset1 ss
  WHERE  rw = 3;
```